# Sampling from Unnormalized Posterior in Prediction Stage

Tags: bayesian, bayesian-network

**Background:**
Given a trained model, $y$, parameterized by $W\text{~} P$ and dataset $D$, for a testing point $x_{test}$, the predictive probability distribution is given by

$$P(y(x_{test})|D) = \int P(y(x_{test})|w)P(w|D)dw \approx \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^NP(y(x_{test})|w_i), w_t\text{~}P(w|D)$$

where we approximate the predictive distribution by the mean of a sample of size $N$ drawn from the posterior $P(w|D), P(w|D)= \frac{P(D|W)P(W)}{\int P(D|W)P(W)dw } \propto P(D|W)P(W)$.

**Questions:** I do understand that we need to estimate the evidence to have a valid probability distribution (i.e., not unnormalized density). However, in the posterior case, we do not care about the *probability value* but rather about *the sample* coming from that distribution. Based on my understanding, there are methods to sample from unnormalized distributions, so in the case of inference (or prediction? I think of these two terms as equivalent), why would we still care about estimating the evidence?

Comment: What do you mean by the phrase "estimate the evidence to have valid probability values", and what does the number 1 have to do with it?  A Gaussian distribution with standard deviation 0.1 has a maximum value of 3.989, for example.

Comment: @jbowman I meant if I am interested in knowing the probability of an event for a stream of data, then I need to have a model that produces valid probability values (i.e., between 0 and 1) such that if I see the value 1, I know for sure that this event is in that chunk of data. However, if it produces unnormalized probabilities like $500,600,4,54,\dots$, then I will not be able to figure out when *for sure* the event is in that chunk of data. All I know is that the higher the number, the more probable that event occurrence.

Comment: So in your case the predictive distribution is a discrete distribution, not a continuous one?

Comment: @jbowman, it can be both. The summation after integral is when we approximate it using Monte Carlo. $N$ here is implicitly considered large enough. My question is if I want to sample from $P(W|D)$ why do I need it to be normalized?

Comment: The sample is not of probabilities but of events.  You approximate the predictive distribution by generating lots of possible future values from the unnormalized distribution (if it's normalized, you can just do the calculations typically).  That sample isn't of probabilities, it's of future values...  I still don't think I understand what you are trying to get at :)

Comment: @jbowman my bad; I think I am using confusing notations. when I wrote $P(W|D)$ I meant the distribution, not the probability values. Based on my understanding, in order to approximate the predictive distribution, we have to approximate the prior distribution $P(D)$, which does not make sense to me as we can sample from the unnormalized posterior distribution. Now you are stating that we generate values from the *unnormalized* which makes me skeptical about my understanding. "(if it's normalized, you can just do the calculations typically)" well if $w$ is high dimensional that wouldn't be easy.

Comment: A sample from the unnormalized posterior distribution *is* an approximation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142099/discussion-between-jbowman-and-rando).